# how to change value of input field through console using js?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bots, focus

I am trying to make a **robot/bot** to do predefined actions on a dedicated website which I will run from console available in Chrome (maybe convert it to extension later).

I'm trying to change the **value** of **input** field to **2**

I tried this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[data-test="input"]')[0].value='2';
```

```html
<input class="InputBase" type="text" data-test="input" placeholder="0" value="1">
```

But as soon as I press **ok button** to *submit* it, the value gets ***reset*** to **1**.

What i noticed is while **entering/clicking** input field **manually** the **class** of `<div>` tag (in which`<input>` tag is used) changed a little , like:

```html
<div class="TextField">` *to this* `<div class="TextField Focused">
```

I have tried clicking(`.click()`), focus(`.focus()`), adding the `Focused` class in `<div>` but the output in console is always `undefined`.

Even tried to change value inside `setinterval()` and then clicked manually on input field(to make it focused) but nothing is happening.

What I think that they are not allowing input through console or what??
Can I do this by interacting with the **API** of **website** (tbh don't know how to interact ?) ?

I have used other **bots** that can do this task , but they are **paid** (so tried to make one by *myself*).

**There can be a way.. Please help**

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: If I run your snippet it works without an issue.

Comment: @Unmitigated  Sorry guys for being Afk for too long. If you want a reproducible example you can go to www.olymptrade.com and enter any random email or password, it will take you to the main trading platform where you can see the chart. I wanted to change the trade amount (located at the right of the screen) through js from console so that I can build a bot.
Let me know if you want further information/details.

Comment: @RuiCosta Updated information now. Please check.

Comment: @Unmitigated It would be really helpful , if you guys can provide a solution.

Comment: @NiteshRanawat Your question will be much easier to answer if you provide a [mre] in the post itself, preferably as a Stack Snippet.